# Wordpress Plug-in vs. CustomPage

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-pages

I am planning to use WP& a premium theme.
I want to customize "pages" to show data from a DB and also their design regarding to show this data.
I am a newbie that's why I am not sure if only creating a custom page template is enough for doing this or a plugin is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a plugin for this. You can either a) modify their template (for example `page.php`) or create your own (`page-custom.php`). This will help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy.

Comment: yup you won't need to develop plugin. here is link good link you can follow it http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/13/guide-wordpress-theme-options/